# Android:Can I have diff versions of my app for various versions of devices

Tags: android, versions

My app shows some problem in devices less than 3.0. Can I have another version (say 1.1) which supports devices less than 3.0 but if I download my app from device with versions greater than 3.0 I should not get 1.1 . How to Implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what you want to know, http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You first need to switch your Google Play developer console to "advanced mode" using the button in the upper right corner of the console.

Then you upload a second APK that has a different `minSdkVersion` defined and activate it. You will then have two APKs active, each supporting a different `minSdkVersion`. Devices will choose the APK with the highest compatible minimum version.

Note that each APK also needs a unique version code.

For more information, see the [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) documentation.

If there are only minor differences in the code between versions, you might also want to consider going the simpler route of branching your code for different versions like so:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    // API 11+ behavior
} else {
    // API < 11 behavior
}
```